# How to apply different text formats to different text in python tkinter Text widget

Tags: python, tkinter, text, widget, editor

I am writing a python code to create a RICH TEXT EDITOR in python[my python text editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpmFs.png). It has a bold button and all formating buttons like italic,fonts etc.

These buttons would format the selected text.

But the problem with all these buttons is that First when I bold the selected text, it is working fine but at the second time it applies the same format to the previously selected text

This is my code for the bold and italic function :

```
def boldtxt():
        bldbtn['activebackground']="#ffad33"
        contboxfont['weight']="bold"
        contbox.tag_add("bold",SEL_FIRST,SEL_LAST)
        contbox.tag_config("bold",font=contboxfont)
def italictxt():


itlbtn['activebackground']="#ffad33"
                contboxfont['slant']="italic"
                contbox.tag_add("italic",SEL_FIRST,SEL_LAST)
                contbox.tag_config("italic",font=contboxfont)
contbox=Text()
contbox.pack()
bldbtn=Button(comand=boldtxt)
bldbtn.pack()
itlbtn=Button(command=italictxt)
itlbtn.pack()
```

I want that every word (or selected item should be formatted according to the user.
For ex.
if the bold button is pressed the selected text should be bold
and if the italic button is pressed then the selected text would be italic.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Are you asking how to combine both bold and italic fonts?

Comment: no i just want one selected text bold and other like bold italic, or bold-underline

Comment: I don't understand what's stopping you from doing that. Make a tag named "bold", one named "italic", one named "bold-italic", etc, and then apply the appropriate tag.

Comment: I am also thinking why it is not so the when i select and apply the style 2nd time then the previously selcted text is formatted in the same way like the second

Answer (score 0):

If you want each word to be *uniquely* formatted, they each need to have a unique tag. In your code, everything uses the "bold" tag, so if you change the "bold" tag, all of the words would change. If you don't want that, each word will need its own unique tag.

Comment: i had given different tags in different functions even if the previously selected text got formatted in the same style

Comment: @SrinjayVatsa: I don't know what you mean. If ranges of text have unique tags, they by definition will have unique properties.

Comment: see the edits i had given some more code to make it clear [ignore the extra indentation]